# MVC5 Owin Signout altering the redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm currently trying to fix an issue where my web application logs out but the login page it gives me an issue of ;

```
Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.
```

Which is caused by the line calling the render action

```
Html.RenderAction("MessageBoard", "Home");
```

I was therefor thinking that I could simple change the signout to return another view (with any render action sections) that simply gives the user the notification that they have signed out.

So currently in my account controller I have

```
 private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
 {
  get
  {
    return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
  }
 }


 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public virtual ActionResult LogOff()
 {

  AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
  // doesnt hit below line as the signout seems to do all the work
  // and redirects back to the login causing issue of child error message
  return RedirectToAction("LogOff");
 }


 // Trying to get the signout to call this method after logoff
 // using RedirectToAction in HTTP Post version.
 public virtual ActionResult Logoff()
 {
   return View();
 }
```

Anyone else experienced this issue or have a better way off overcoming my shortcomings :).

Cheers

Comment: I don't think the SignOut does the redirect. Are you sure (by debugging) that the RedirectToAction is not hit? Does your controller have the Authorize attribute? This could cause the RedirectToAction to redirect to the login page first, because in that case the LogOff action needs authorization.

Comment: Yep it does actually hit the line, my comment should have said hits the line but does nothing :(. Add a breakpoint in the other Logoff method doesn't get hit.

Comment: OK, what about my other question? I really think the Logoff is not available for not-authenticated users (by Authorize attribute on the controller or a generic authorize check). You can verify this to visit the logoff page directly when your signed out.

Comment: @kloarubeek sorry your correct , that was the bit I was overlooking , arhhhh forgot about the attribute on this adding [AllowAnonymous] fixed my issue about the redirect. cheers for assist. +1 ( I would vote you up if i could )